# Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element' while using Apify Web Scraper

Tags: web-scraping, apify

I'm trying to use the Apify Web Scraper to scrape the page of an app on Play Store and retrieve some info to build a custom RSS feed, similar to what is shown [here](https://blog.apify.com/how-to-turn-any-website-into-an-rss-feed-a8f9f216e1b0/). However, when I run my task, the output gives me the following error:

```
ERROR PuppeteerCrawler: handleRequestFunction failed, reclaiming failed request back to the list or queue {"url":"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate&hl=en&gl=US","retryCount":1,"id":"RiHGfpYUb4PuquI"}
2022-08-27T07:13:48.079Z   Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment.
2022-08-27T07:13:48.081Z       at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:4931:16
2022-08-27T07:13:48.083Z       at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:4939:4
2022-08-27T07:13:48.085Z       at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:36:3
2022-08-27T07:13:48.087Z       at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:40:4
2022-08-27T07:13:48.089Z       at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/home/myuser/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:175:23)
2022-08-27T07:13:48.091Z       at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
2022-08-27T07:13:48.093Z       at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (/home/myuser/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
2022-08-27T07:13:48.095Z       at async /home/myuser/src/crawler_setup.js:333:42
2022-08-27T07:13:48.097Z       at async PuppeteerCrawler._executeHooks (/home/myuser/node_modules/apify/build/crawlers/basic_crawler.js:592:17)
2022-08-27T07:13:48.099Z       at async PuppeteerCrawler._handleNavigation (/home/myuser/node_modules/apify/build/crawlers/browser_crawler.js:405:9)
2022-08-27T07:13:48.101Z       at async PuppeteerCrawler._handleRequestFunction (/home/myuser/node_modules/apify/build/crawlers/browser_crawler.js:343:13)
2022-08-27T07:13:48.103Z       at async wrap (/home/myuser/node_modules/@apify/timeout/index.js:73:27)
```

Not only this is my first time using Apify, as this is also the first time I face this error regarding 'TrustedHTML'. I think it may have something to do with the jQuery injection option from the Apify settings, but I'm not sure.

This is the code I put into the 'Page function' boilerplate:

```
// The function accepts a single argument: the "context" object.
// For a complete list of its properties and functions,
// see https://apify.com/apify/web-scraper#page-function 
async function pageFunction(context) {
    // This statement works as a breakpoint when you're trying to debug your code. Works only with Run mode: DEVELOPMENT!
    // debugger; 
    // jQuery is handy for finding DOM elements and extracting data from them.
    // To use it, make sure to enable the "Inject jQuery" option.
    if (context.request.url === 'https://play.google.com/stor/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate&hl=en&gl=US') return;
    const $ = context.jQuery;
    const title = $('h1').first().text();
    const date = $('.xg1aie').text();
    const description = $('.SfzRHd')
        .next() // Skip the <div> in between
        .text();
    const isoDate = new Date(date).toUTCString();

    // Print some information to actor log
    context.log.info(`URL: ${context.request.url}, TITLE: ${title}`);

    // Manually add a new page to the queue for scraping.
   await context.enqueueRequest({ url: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube&hl=en&gl=US' });

    // Return an object with the data extracted from the page.
    // It will be stored to the resulting dataset.
    return {
        url: context.request.url,
        title,
        date: isoDate,
        guid: isoDate,
        description
    };
}
```

Comment: Take a look into https://apify.com/katerinahronik/google-play-reviews

Comment: GitHub: https://github.com/katacek/google-play-reviews

Comment: Quick tip: do NOT use jQuery cause it violates the TrustedTypes browser protection from XSS attacks. More info here: https://web.dev/trusted-types/

Comment: Use native processing to avoid using innerHtml instead of vanilla js `document.createElement`

Comment: I've seen this one for Google Play reviews, but what I really want is to build a rss feed to know whenever some apps get updates and their recent changes. Anyway, I'll take a look into that link about trusted types and I'll also test it without jQuerry as you suggested

Comment: I got rid of the trustedHTML error by using vanilla JS, thanks! I had to make some other changes in the code as well, but so far, so good.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the remarks by Artur Mustafin, you don't need to give up the injection of external scripts. You can use two options that will allow you to inject jQuery (or any other code) even if CSP is enabled on the page.

[image]

This effectively bypasses the usual security that you'd see in a browser and allow you to "XSS" the website without issues.